# How to merge local branch to an updated master while keeping changes in the new master?

Tags: git, github

I have a local and remote repository using Git and GitHub. Lets say the repo is just two files. fileA.html and fileB.html

I start a branch locally and make changes to fileA.html, then push it up to the remote GitHub repo in its own branch (not master). Someone else pulls down the master, makes changes to fileB.html and pushes them to the master and now the remote master is changed.

I'm still working on my own branch and my goal is to merge my branch into the master (with the new changes).

I can do a git pull origin master, and now my local master is up to date. However, when I started my branch, the changes to fileB.html didn't exist. If I do a merge to my local master then push it up will those changes be overridden? or will they stay? Although my local master is now updated, I feel as though I need to update my branch with the changes that happened to the master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the flow:

```
$ git checkout master
```

Pull new changes to keep master as remote:

```
$ git pull
```

Now to update your branch with the latest changes:

```
$ git checkout your-branch
```

Merge master into your branch:

```
$ git merge master
```

At this point, `fileB.html` will be as the remote and since you are only working in `fileA.html` you should not have any `merge conflicts`, once you are finished working in your branch you could do a `pull request` so that someone could review your changes and if approved then your branch could be merged in to `master`.

To `merge` your branch into master you could do:

```
$ git checkout master
```

and then:

```
$ git merge your-branch
```

This is the basic way of doing it, you could use `rebase` to avoid merge commits, for example, you could do this flow:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout your-branch
$ git rebase master
$ git checkout master
$ git merge your-branch
```

This will do a `fast forward` and then to push your changes:

```
$ git push
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on branch A, and there is changes in master, you can pull those changes into your current branch A with `git pull origin master`

When you push, your changes and the other changes will be then there in your branch A (remote).

If you are using Github, then normally you will create a merge request from branch A to master that can then be reviewed & merged.